# Make sed to replace capture group with corresponding environment variable

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Assuming we have source_file.json of the following content:

```json
 {
   "someVar": "__SOME_ENV_VAR__",
   "anotherVar": "__ANOTHER_ENV_VAR__",
   "yetAnotherVar": "__ONE_MORE_ENV_VAR__"
 }
```

How do I

- Search for environment variable placeholder (using the pattern `__([A-Z_]\+)__`
- Interpolate capturing group (`([A-Z_]\+)` part) as `\1` to the value of the environment variable that matches the capturing group (i.e. `SOME_ENV_VAR`, `ANOTHER_ENV_VAR`, `ONE_MORE_ENV_VAR`)
- Replace the capturing group with the value of the corresponding environment variable

I tried to approach this problem from two different angles (with numerous variations)

#### ***No1:*** search and replace in one go using `sed`

```bash
sed -i "s/__([A-Z_]\+)__/${\1}/g" source_file.json
```

#### ***No2 (worse one):*** search and replace all env var occurrences

```bash
env | while IFS='=' read -r key value; do
  sed -i "s/__$key__/$value/g"
done
```

But none of them did particularly work all failing with different kinds of errors or coming short of interpolating the environment variable and outputting something like `"someVar": "$SOME_ENV_VAR"`.

None of the posts related to the subject cover this particular case (interpolation of a capturing group). Most of them cover the scenario with specific environment variables to be interpolated known ahead of time.

> ***Note:*** above has to go into /bin/sh script that has to be executed inside Alpine-based docker container and thus no hassle with basetext package installation (to use `envsubst`) considered as an option

Comment: Even if you can't install a tool that understands JSON `sed` is a bad choice for this as it'll fail in various ways given various contents of the environment variables since it doesn't understand literal strings, see [is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed), you should be looking for a solution using a tool that does understand literal strings, e.g. `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `/bin/sh` of the image is Bash, then you could use a loop to build a Bash array with the replacement commands, and then call `sed`:

```
replacements=()
while IFS='=' read -r key value; do
  replacements+=(-e "s/__${key}__/$value/")
done < <(env)

sed -i "${replacements[@]}" /path/to/file
```

If it is not Bash, then you could create a `sed` script with a loop, and then pass that to `sed` (thanks [@tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) for the nudge):

```
script=/tmp/sed.txt

env | while IFS='=' read -r key value; do
  echo "s/__${key}__/$value/"
done > "$script"

sed -f "$script" -i /path/to/file
```

Both approaches have the weakness that they break if the `value` (or the `key`) contains the pattern and replace separator `/` in the `s///` command of `sed`. If there is a symbol that is guaranteed to be not used by any `key` and `value`, then you can use that. For example instead of `s///`, the command can be written as `s???`.

Comment: They'd also break if the `value` contained `&`, or `\1` or similar backreference, or (unlikely given the OPs example) the `key` contained any space or regexp metachar, or if `__${key}__` occurred in other contexts, or if `value` happened to contain a string that matched some other `key`, or if `value` contained a double quote (would corrupt the output), etc.

Comment: It would also replace text that doesn't match the OPs criteria for the strings to be replaced, e.g. if `_____` (5 underscores `_`) existed anywhere in the input it'd get replaced with the path to the last command you executed since `env` would output `_=/path/to/command`.

Answer (score 3):

`sed` is the wrong tool for working with JSON data. Use something that understands the format, like [`jq`, the de-facto standard command line JSON tool](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/). You can even still use regular expressions to find the values to substitute, and, unlike `sed`, directly access environment variables (Presented as a JSON object):

```bash
# Assuming appropriate environment variables have been defined
$ jq 'with_entries(.value |= gsub("__(?<name>.*?)__"; $ENV[.name]))' source_file.json
{
  "someVar": "a",
  "anotherVar": "b",
  "yetAnotherVar": "c"
}
```

For each value of each element of the top level object (I assume they're always going to be a simple string like your sample), replace every occurrence of `__FOO__` with the contents of the environment variable `FOO`.

An alternative that adjusts every non-object-key string in the object, no matter how deeply nested, is

```bash
jq 'walk(if type == "string" then gsub("__(?<name>.*?)__"; $ENV[.name]) else . end)' source_file.json
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the tool for JSON (yet my question was more general and my actual source file is not JSON). Nevertheless, as I noted above, no additional tools are considered as "find-and-replace" problem seems to be trivial enough to be solved by default Alpine toolbox.

Comment: @S.Rullio *my actual source file is not JSON* Then why in the world does your question include a JSON source file? You're not going to get good answers to X if you're asking about Y.

Comment: You also have a `bash` tag when you're using `sh`? Another source of confusion to people.

Comment: As a careful reader, you should've noticed that there's no indication whatsoever in the initial post that the solution working for JSON **exclusively** was sought. Furthermore, the message implying that no 3rd party tools are considered was delivered in a quite comprehensive manner at the bottom of the post. Most of the features of `bash` are still relevant in `sh` hence the tag. Hopefully, that helped to connect the dots between X and Y for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're OK with using GNU sed you must also have GNU awk so here's a GNU awk solution that's much more robust than a sed solution both in terms of the strings it matches and which characters the strings and replacement variables can contain:

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/^(\s*"[^"]+"\s*:\s*")__([A-Z_]+)__(",?\s*)$/,a) {
    old = a[2]
    if ( old in ENVIRON ) {
        new = ENVIRON[old]
        $0 = a[1] new a[3]
    }
}
{ print }
```

```
$ export SOME_ENV_VAR='~!@#$%^&*()_+=-{}[]|\:;"'\''<,>.?/'
$ echo "$SOME_ENV_VAR"
~!@#$%^&*()_+=-{}[]|\:;"'<,>.?/

$ export ANOTHER_ENV_VAR='this \
> contains some \
> newlines'
$ echo "$ANOTHER_ENV_VAR"
this \
contains some \
newlines
```

```
$ cat file
 {
   "someVar": "__SOME_ENV_VAR__",
   "anotherVar": "__ANOTHER_ENV_VAR__",
   "yetAnotherVar": "__ONE_MORE_ENV_VAR__"
 }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
 {
   "someVar": "~!@#$%^&*()_+=-{}[]|\:;"'<,>.?/",
   "anotherVar": "this \
contains some \
newlines",
   "yetAnotherVar": "__ONE_MORE_ENV_VAR__"
 }
```

With the above you can sanitize `new` to match JSON rules if necessary, e.g. you may want to put a `\` in front of an unescaped `"`, before using it in the output.

Just like GNU sed has `-i`, GNU awk has `-i inplace` if you find that useful vs just using a tmp file.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have:

```
export SOME_ENV_VAR="a"
export ANOTHER_ENV_VAR="b"

echo '{
   "someVar": "__SOME_ENV_VAR__",
   "anotherVar": "__ANOTHER_ENV_VAR__",
   "yetAnotherVar": "__ONE_MORE_ENV_VAR__"
 }' >file
```

You can use Ruby:

```
ruby -r json -e 'print JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.load($<.read).map{|k,v| 
    if v =~ /^__(.*)__$/ && ENV[$1]
        [k,ENV[$1] ]
    else
        [k,"NOT FOUND"]
    end
    }.to_h)
' file
```

Prints:

```
{
  "someVar": "a",
  "anotherVar": "b",
  "yetAnotherVar": "NOT FOUND"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving it a shot. However, the crucial point about the solution that was sought (as I stressed at the bottom of the initial post) - it has to work in pure /bin/sh in the Alpine-based container. Therefore, unless we're not talking ruby:alpine, setting up Ruby for the sole purpose of search-and-replace in one file is a bit of an overkill. Nevertheless, thanks again for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ export SOME_ENV_VAR=foo
$ export ANOTHER_ENV_VAR=bar

$ awk -F'__' -v OFS= '
    NR==FNR{
        match($0,/^([^=]*)=(.*)$/,a); 
        map[a[1]]=a[2]; 
        next
    } 
    NF==3 && $2 in map{$2=map[$2]}
1' <(env) file
{
  "someVar": "foo",
  "anotherVar": "bar",
  "yetAnotherVar": "__ONE_MORE_ENV_VAR__"
}
```